# Относительный путь не работает RewriteRule .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, редирект, mod-rewrite

Я хочу добавить на сайт возможность выбирать язык, но чтобы файл index.php был тотже.

Итак, сайт на /index.php, по запросу /lang/en GET запрос передаёться, index.php грузиться. Но стили, картинки и тд, грузяться почему то по пути /lang/..., почему добавляеться lang не понимаю.

То есть сайт можно открыть по https://example.com/

Он также открывается по https://example.com/lang/gh (gh это любые два символа), и в GET передаётся переменная (успешно).

Но относительные пути почему-то открываються например вот так /lang/styles/styles.css, а должно быть /styles/styles.css

Мой .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.*)(lang)(/)(..)(.*) $1$5index.php?$2=$4 [L]
```

Есть идеи? (я в курсе, что можно указывать абсолютный путь. Но я хочу скрыть директорию от пользователя, поэтому этот вариант не подходит)

Comment: потому что стили у вас и прочее подключены по относительному пути `href="styles/style.css"` а надо  от корня `href="/styles.style.php"`, тогда и проблем не будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самое начало в корень добавил это:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# чтобы редирект был только для стилей, картинок и тд.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} css [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} styles [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} js [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} img
RewriteRule (.*)lang/(.*) $1$2 [L,R]
```

Теперь грузиться всё. Нужно ещё доработать схему, чтобы добавить ещё функции, но уже прогресс.